# Algorithm complexity for this function

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, time-complexity

```
def mystery(L):

sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
bound = 1
while bound <= len(L):
    i = 0
    while i < bound:
        j = 0
        while j < len(L):
            if L[j] > L[i]:
                sum1 = sum1 + L[j]
            j = j + 2
        j = 1
        while j < len(L):
            sum2 = sum2 + L[j]
            j = j*2
        i = i + 1

    bound = bound * 2
return sum1 + sum2
```

I am having trouble finding the complexity of this function. I got to the i loop and don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky to sort out how many times the middle level `while` loop runs. The outer loop increases `bound` by a factor of two on each pass (up to `len(L)`), which means the `i` loop will run `O(bound)` times per pass for `O(log(N))` passes (where `N` is `len(L)`). The tricky part is how to add up the `bound` values, since they're changing on each pass.

I think the easiest way to figure out the sum is to start with the largest `bound`, just before the loop quits. First, lets assume that `N` (aka `len(L)`) is a power of 2. Then the last `bound` value will be exactly equal to `N`. The next smaller one (used on the next to last iteration) will be `N/2` and the next after that will be `N/4`. Their sum will be:

```
N + N/2 + N/4 + N/8 + ... + 1
```

If we factor out `N` from each term, we'll get:

```
N*(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... + 1/N)
```

You should recognize the sum in the parentheses, it's a simple geometric series (the sum of the powers of `1/2`), which comes up pretty often in mathematics and analysis. If the sum went on forever, it would add up exactly to `2`. Since we're quitting a bit early, it will be less than two by an amount equal to the last term (`1/N`). When we multiply the `N` term in again, we get the whole thing as being run `2*N - 1` times, so the loop is `O(N)`

The same Big-O bound works when `N` is not exactly a power of 2, since the values we added up in the analysis above will each serve as the upper bound for one of the actual `bound` values we will see in the loop.

So, the `i` loop runs `O(N)` times.